# use group by clause and count() in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Table : Class

```
class_id    ClassName
----------------------
1           AAA
2           BBB
3           CCC
```

Table : Groups

```
id    class_id   GroupName
---------------------------
1      1          A1
2      1          A2
3      2          B1
4      3          C1
5      2          B2
6      1          A3
```

Expected Output :

```
class_id   ClassName  count(*)
-------------------------------
1          AAA         3
2          BBB         2
3          CCC         1
```

Comment: Not clear what the question is

Comment: What did you try? And lease format your question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Inner Join to get result :

```
SELECT        Class.class_id, Class.ClassName, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM            Class INNER JOIN
                         Groups ON Class.class_id = Groups.class_id
GROUP BY Class.class_id, Class.ClassName
```